# How to pass list to angular array

Tags: angularjs

I am a new to angular... I have an object list that I would like to pass to angular and use the ng-repeat function.

Using NameList that was passed from my controller, I would like to display a list of id-names-states. Before, I did the following...

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.NameList) {
    <li>item.id - item.names - item.states</li> }
</ul>
```

the list would be something like...

```
 id: '1', name: 'John Doe', city: 'Phoenix' 
 id: '2', name: 'Tony Hope', city: 'Queens' 
 id: '3', name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'Frederick' 
 id: '4', name: 'John Smith', city: 'Miami' 
 id: '5', name: 'Tom Ford', city: 'Atlanta'
```

After realizing angulars capabilities I would like to set up the list, with the ability to have the user filter based on names

So my question is, How do I pass the NameList object to get populated with angular, or can I just populate the object and tie the list to angular somehow?

This is what I have so far

```
<div id="angularWrapper" data-ng-app="" data-ng-controller ="SimpleController">
    <div>Name:
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
    </div>
    @*I would like to pass Model.NameList to customers*@
    <div data-ng-model="@Model.NameList"></div>        
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{cust.id + - + cust.name + - + cust.state}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to call the server and load the results into the `$scope.customers`?

Comment: I don't want to call the server. The NameList object comes from initial load.

Comment: You are going to need to expand your question. Needs more details. We don't know what `Model.NameList` is.

Comment: Good point @Jesus. I hope the edits makes the situation a bit clearer

Comment: @MrM If you want to pass data from asp.net to angular, you can put a new API controller and request the data from angular.

Comment: @JesusRodriguez that's where I am stumped... I had the answer posted by Beterraba set in a controller, but I just don't know how to pass the data to angular for the setup

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
$scope.customers = [
  { id: '1', name: 'John Doe', city: 'Phoenix' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Tony Hope', city: 'Queens' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'Frederick' },
  { id: '4', name: 'John Smith', city: 'Miami' },
  { id: '5', name: 'Tom Ford', city: 'Atlanta' }
];
```

Comment: demo here : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hofNNXi9YCeQ7shw1bcz?p=preview), but why question is tagged C# & asp.net & .net ?

Comment: @dawuut because he wants to pass info from C# to angular.

Comment: The list will not be hard coded to customers, like @JesusRodriguez said, the object will be coming from C#

Comment: @MrM Then you shouldnt do comments like: "I don't want to call the server." :-P.

Comment: @Beterraba.. apologies

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about how AngularJS binding works, you should read the guide on Data Binding: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding

In the meantime here's a simple JSFiddle I think does what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/75WPW/1/

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name">{{cust.id}} - {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
 angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','mySrv',function ($scope,mySrv) {
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.customers = [];

        $scope.customers = mySrv.getCustomers();
    }])
    // fake service, substitute with your server call ($http)
    .factory('mySrv',function(){
        var customers = [
            {id: '1', name: 'John Doe', city: 'Phoenix'},
            {id: '2', name: 'Tony Hope', city: 'Queens'},
            {id: '3', name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'Frederick'},
            {id: '4', name: 'John Smith', city: 'Miami'},
            {id: '5', name: 'Tom Ford', city: 'Atlanta'}
        ];
        return {
            getCustomers : function(){
                return customers;
            }
        };
    });
```

You could also set `$scope.customers` by using the resolve function of your route.

Comment: I should note that the service call here is just to demonstrate how you may want to set up a server call, but in the service you're going to want to use **promises**, generated by calling `$http` or by using `$resource` and `$q` this way your interface isn't waiting on the server to finish.  Although as I said before if this is all in a `ngRoute` then you may want to use the route's **resolve** function.

Comment: This was actually helpful by pointing me in right direction. Thanks @m.e.conroy

Comment: Great, glad I could help you out

Comment: I should point out that the filter in the example will not only filter by name property of an object but by every property of the object so if you start typing the name of a city it will also filter on that.  You can however filter on just a specific property, you'd have to change your ngModel from just name to something like `name.id` or `name.name` or `name.city`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that may have a possible alternative...

```
<div id="angularWrapper" data-ng-app="demoApp" data-ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <div>
        Name:
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="eg in List | filter: name">{{ eg.Name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var scope = angular.element('#angularWrapper').scope();
            @foreach (var npo in Model.NameList)
            { 
                @: scope.AddList({ Name: '@eg.Name' });
            }
            scope.$apply();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

**.js file**

```
function getList() {
var self = this;
self.Name = "";
}

var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
demoApp.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController); //could just load the function($scope) from simplecontroller..

function SimpleController($scope) {
$scope.List = [];
$scope.AddList = function (data) {
    var eg = new getList();
    eg.Name = data.Name;
    $scope.List.push(eg);
}
}
```